# Not able to connect Coldfusion 9 to Sybase

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, sqlanywhere

I am trying to add a datasource in the ColdFusion 9 administrator by connecting it to a Sybase database. I even supplied the port number as 2638 (Sybase).  But I keep getting errors like:

> unable to connect and connection limits reached

What should I do to allow CF to communicate with Sybase ODBC?  Should I install JDBC? Any precautions or specific steps to follow? The Adobe documentation seems to be incomplete.

*Environment:*

- Vista
- ColdFusion 9
- Sybase 6.1.0 (SQL Anywhere 12 / QAnywhere 12)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install "jConnect". Kindly look at the following links:

- [Configuring the Sybase jConnect 5.5 driver](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/185/tn_18591.html)
- [Data Source Management > Connecting to Sybase](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fe0.html)

Answer (score 1):

"Connection limit reached" implies that you are using the personal server (dbeng12.exe), which has a limit of 10 simultaneous connections and does not allow connections over a network. You likely need to use the network server (dbsrv12.exe) which has no connection limit (other than licensing) and *does* allow network connections.

*Disclaimer: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.*